# How to interpret the Ljung-Box test output?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, p-value

I am trying to forecast the univariate time series using two different neural networks. After training and testing, I have residuals (Actual - Prediction) with me for both networks say `N1.R` and `N2.R`. Now I want to perform the Ljung-Box test for both networks. I used `lbqtest` function implemented in MATLAB with three input parameters i.e. residuals, lags, and degree-of-freedom. The function returned four different values h, pValue, stat, and cValue. Could anyone explain how to interpret all four values and how to compare two different models' prediction accuracy based on these results? For instance, `S` is a univariate series of random numbers. After applying two different models `N1=mean(S)*rand()+rand(10, 1)` and `N2=mean(S)*rand()-rand(10, 1)` the forecasts and residuals are mentioned below. The computed residuals are passed to `lbqtest(residuals, lags, dof)` function implemented in Matlab with `lags=2` and `dof=1;`.

`S = {0.6377, 0.9577, 0.2407, 0.6761, 0.2891, 0.6718, 0.6951, 0.0680, 0.2548, 0.2240}`

`N1.forecast = {1.1593, 0.6594, 1.0954, 0.9902, 0.3216, 0.9171, 0.7017, 1.2309, 0.3160, 0.7773}`

`N1.residuals ={-0.5216, 0.2983, -0.8547, -0.3141, -0.0325, -0.2453, -0.0065,   -1.1629, -0.0612, -0.5533}`

`N2.forecast ={-0.2608, -0.5701, -0.1224, -0.5847,  -0.2713, 0.1643, 0.0242,   -0.5217, -0.2734, 0.0474}`

`N2.residuals = {0.8985, 1.5278, 0.3631, 1.2608, 0.5603, 0.5075, 0.6709, 0.5897, 0.5282, 0.1767}`

The values received for both models from the test are:

`N1.h=1, N1.p=0.0366, N1.stat=4.3702, N1.cval=3.8415`

`N2.h=0, N2.p=0.2199, N2.stat=1.5049, N2.cval=3.8415`

My question is how to interpret these results and compare the forecast accuracy using these values?

**Request**: If possible, please explain in simple words (without using statistics vocabulary too much).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please at least include some output. If you require users to know the particular implementation of Matlab, you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for the suggestion. I have made changes in the question itself.